# How to get full qualified file name in ANTLR4 errorlistener

Tags: java, antlr4

I'm implementing the method syntaxError in BaseErrorListener in ANTLR4.

I have many files with the same name but in different paths.
I can't figure out how to get the fully qualified file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the FQN of the source file being parsed, try:

```
 Parser parser = (Parser) recognizer;
 TokenStream tokens = parser.getInputStream();
 String name = tokens.getSourceName();
```